# Hash[string.split(...)] vs Hash[*string.split(...)]

Tags: ruby, hash

Trying to understand why this returns a nice populated hash:

```
 Hash[*myString.split("\n")]
```

While this returns an empty hash?

```
 Hash[myString.split("\n")]
```

I see that the asterisk is the key, which signifies a variable length argument... but one of the requirements of Hash[...] is that it can take an even numbered array and turn it into a valid hash. Well, in my second example above, the string.split on a new line is returning an even numbered array, so why doesn't Ruby allow it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the splat `*` character expands the array into each individual element, rather than passing in the array as a whole. From the Ruby 2.0 Hash documentation:

```
Hash["a", 100, "b", 200]             #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200}
Hash[ [ ["a", 100], ["b", 200] ] ]   #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200}
Hash["a" => 100, "b" => 200]         #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200}
```

passing in the elements using the `Hash[]` method simply formats the hash as you would expect. Compare that with

```
Hash[ Array.new ]
```

which returns an empty hash, because you're essentially giving it an odd number of arguments, which won't map to a proper hash.

Comment: Excellent answer. When you said the splat character expands the array into each individual element, it clicked for me. Passing an Array doesn't count as passing multiple parameters, as it is just one object. Thanks! (will mark as answer once the site allows me to).

Comment: Glad I could help! Actually I had never thought of instantiating hashes using this method, so looking at the documentation taught me a thing or two!

Answer (score 1):

Totally agree with the existing answer, but here's a more explicit example which may clarify why the splat is needed in this case:

```
test_string = "my\ntest\nstring"

[test_string.split("\n")]  #=> [["my", "test", "string"]]
[*test_string.split("\n")] #=> ["my", "test", "string"]
```

So as you can see, without the splat you are giving `Hash[]` a single argument (an array), rather than multiple arguments.